# SimpleDateFormat with a pattern results in error Unparseable Date

Tags: java, datetime

I'm attempting to do something extremely simple - take the current date and time, and parse it in the desired format.

```
private final String datePattern = "yyyy:DDD";
private final String timePattern = "hh:mm:ss";

public void setDateAndTime(){

  // Default constructor initializes to current date/time
  Date currentDateAndTime = new Date();

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
  SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timePattern);

  try {

   this.date = dateFormatter.parse(currentDateAndTime.toString());
   this.time = timeFormatter.parse(currentDateAndTime.toString());

  } catch (ParseException e){
   System.out.println("Internal error - unable to parse date/time");
   System.exit(1);
  }

 }
```

This results in an exception:

> Unparseable date: "Sat Nov 06 11:04:22 EDT 2010"

This is a perfectly valid date string, and the patterns I am using to initialize the SimpleDateFormat seem to be correct.

How can this error be avoided, and how can the `SimpleDateFormat` be initialized as above?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: this is the wrong place to call `System.exit()`. Don't you rather want to just `throw` the exception or `return` from the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *parsing* is getting a `Date` from a `String`
- *formatting* is getting a `String` from a `Date`

You need the latter - so use `formatter.format(currentDateAndTime)`

You are getting the exception, because you transform your `Date` to `String` by `toString()` which you later try to parse, but which does not follow the format you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

you code should be

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(timePattern);
System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(currentDateAndTime));`

Simply put, you cannot format a date object unless the output is a string